# Can I set the GOPATH using the go command line tool?

Tags: go, gopath

I would like to set GOPATH using the go tool upon compilation, just like adding an include path in C/++. I want the gopath to be used only within a certain project. Can this be done without setting an environment variable?

Comment: On unix, prefix the `go` command with setting the env var, e.g. `GOPATH=XXX go build .`

Comment: @icza thats a solution, but I would like to refrain from using environment variables in general. Plus, I'm on windows :)

Comment: You can use `go env -w GOPATH="..."`. That is not a system environment variable, but that is a global setting.

Comment: `go env` has `-w` flag and `-u` flag. `-w` sets a Go environment variable and `-u` unsets it. However, there does not seem to be a way to combine it into a single command while building, so you'll need to manually set it up, run the build, then unset it.

Comment: Why do you want to set the GOPATH at all (and even per projekt)?

Comment: And as @TehSphinX noted, this may cause problem if there somehow other build process is caught between the set and unset, as it is global setting.

Comment: @TehSphinX so if I do it your way, the environment variable will 'go out of scope' after the command ends?

Comment: @TehSphinX because I like it when all of my dependencies are in the same location, in my repository.

Comment: No, it is a global setting that stays until set otherwise.

Comment: @TehSphinX is there a way to make it a 'local' environment var?

Comment: @Serket: Have you looked into working with Go modules? That is the correct way and there is no need to manipulate the GOPATH at all.

Comment: @TehSphinX No I haven't. Could you explain or provide some resources for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to have a GOPATH per project to separate dependencies, work with Go modules.

A short intro on `Go modules`: https://ncona.com/2020/10/introduction-to-golang-modules/

Indepth, official intro: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

---

My intro:

In your repository call `go init yourModuleName` to start working with go modules.

Once initialized, to me the most important command is `go mod tidy`. You call that and it cleans up your go.mod/go.sum files, removing what is not needed and adding what is needed.

To add a new dependency call `go get dependencyname` from within your project folder to add it to your `go.mod` file and be able to use it in your code.

To update a dependency, just call `go get dependencyname` again and it will update the version to the latest available in `go.mod` file.